# Javascript - How to simplify a range of characters for conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am editing a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285898/javascript-change-input-letter-before-written-down-textarea) to make an alphabet convert into another set alphabet, in other words, my intention is to make an online textarea keyboard for a foreign alphabet.

This is my code which I have edited from above:

```
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#txt').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
    var $txt = $('#txt');
    e.preventDefault();
if(pressedKey == 'q') {$txt.val($txt.val() + 'ф');}
if(pressedKey == 'w') {$txt.val($txt.val() + 'ц');}
if(pressedKey == 'e') {$txt.val($txt.val() + 'у');}
if(pressedKey == '') {$txt.val($txt.val() + '');} .......
});
</script>
```

For every latin alphabet there is one cyrillic alphabet. Considering there are uppercase letters and punctuation marks as well, there are certainly a lot of '`if(pressedKey == '') {$txt.val($txt.val() + '');}`'s to make.

How can I simplify this code, instead of making more than 50 rows of almost the same line?

I have referred to many sources and have tried many approaches with my short knowledge, I also tried to include `var` into my Javascript as many sources recommended doing so, but cannot think of a good way. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Don't use that snippet.** You should not change the behavior of typing inside a textarea. Just for example, Insert some characters, now move to the first charater with your caret. insert a character. Where is your caret now? c'mon ;)

Comment: Solution for @RokoC.Buljan valid issue with using `$txt.val(...)`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4605347/2181514

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for your advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a object and use the `pressedKey` as key, like:

```
const characters = {
  'q': 'ф'
}
const newCharacter = characters[pressedKey] || '?'

$txt.val($txt.val() + newCharacter);
```

Or even less, but you lose a bit of meaning:

```
$txt.val($txt.val() + ({ 'q': 'ф' })[pressedKey])
```

Comment: destructuring (your 2nd example) instead or direct referencing is always a less better idea. Writing *cool* code does not mean it's the ideal or even more readable way to go.